# Can I use face-recogition npm package in react?

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, npm

I'm learning react and ***I'm trying to implement an npm package called [face-recognition](https://www.npmjs.com/package/face-recognition) in my react project.***

But it looks like that their documentation is for nodejs. I've looked into the source code of the package which seems that it doesn't export any module so I just imported it. But still, my console is giving me the error **ModuleNotFoundError**

**Inshort:** Can I use this [face-recognition](https://www.npmjs.com/package/face-recognition) library in my react.js?

Here is my live code in [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/elegant-saha-vlb3f?file=/src/Home.js)

Below is the raw code of the same file.

```
import React from "react";
import "face-recognition";

import image1 from "./assets/fFace.jpg";
import image2 from "./assets/mFace.jpg";

const Home = () => {
  const imageOne = image1;
  const win = new fr.ImageWindow();

  // display image
  win.setImage(imageOne);

  const detector = fr.FaceDetector(imageOne);
  // detect all faces
  const faceRectangles = detector.locateFaces(imageOne);
  return (
    <>
      <h1>Face Recognition</h1>
      {faceRectangles}
    </>
  );
};

export default Home;
```

Answer (score 0):

From the [npm](https://www.npmjs.com/package/face-recognition#this-package-is-pretty-much-obsolete-i-recommend-you-to-switch-to-face-apijs--which-covers-the-same-functionality-as-face-recognitionjs-in-a-nodejs-as-well-as-browser-environment) page

> This package is pretty much obsolete. I recommend you to switch to face-api.js, which covers the same functionality as face-recognition.js in a nodejs as well as browser environment.

Comment: I know it's obsolete. But, I'm just asking if it's possible to use this library with react or not?